# How to include a list of symbols?

Tags: symbols

[image]

Is there a special way, a standard way to include a list of symbols in a LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[]{algpseudocode}
```

I have a few possibly ambiguous symbols, like the `\odot` which would benefit from a definition.

I mean something like you might have at the start of a linear algebra book: `$\odot$` – Hadamard product, ...

Comment: I mean something like you might have at the start of a linear algebra book: $ \odot $ : Hadamard product, ...

Comment: like in the pic i just added, a list of symbols

Comment: Hmm, what does this relate to pseudocodes?

Comment: To make that you only have to make a `\chapter*{List of Symbols}` and a table in it.

Comment: because I used the Hadamard product symbol, for example

Comment: Then just add that symbol to the table. You don't even have to load `algorithm` and `algpseudocode`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the algorithms etc. You may use `glossaries` or `nomencl` to generate a list of symbols.

Answer (score 3):

A quick, simple and (very) dirty way.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{List of Symbols}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    $+$ & Addition Operator\\
    $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
    $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
    $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
    $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
    $\Leftrightarrow$ & Bar Foo
\end{tabular}
\chapter{Check chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Check chapter}
\section{Check section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very error-prone, in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, this is not a standard one, and I said it is very dirty.